# Google Cloud Messaging: Can Send Messages, but Can't Receive

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm taking a crack at using Google Cloud Messaging in my Android app, but I am encountering difficulty. I have successfully been able to have my app sync its registration token with my app server, and that part seems to be working how the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) describes it. As I understand it, I need a service in my app that extends GcmListenerService, and I must override the onMessageReceived method to handle the message. Here is my implementation of that class, which I basically copy verbatim from the [example repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart):

```
public class GCMListenerService 
                    extends com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d("response", message);
    }
}
```

I have also updated my manifest accordingly, to account for this new service:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="xx.xx.xx.gcm" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="xx.xx.xx.GCMListenerService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Despite all this, the onMessageReceived method never executes. To test it, I have been sending an HTTP post in the form of a JSON object to https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send, where the "to" field is set to the token created by my InstanceIdListener class. After the successful post, I get a message similar to the following:

```
Response:     
{"multicast_id":7148018997883491563,
"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,
"results":[{"message_id":"long string that never changes"}]}
```

My Android device is connected to the internet, which I am certain of because I have a basic login server that correctly authenticates login credentials over the network as well, which works correctly.

I have tried calling startService(), despite the fact that the example app in that repo I linked above never seems to. Whether I do so or not, the result is still silence after I send the message. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Do you also have an implementation of the InstanceIDListenerService? (asking because it´s not included in your excerpt of your manifest)
And second: Does the category-tag of your GcmReceiver´s intent-filter equal your root package defined in the manifest´s package-tag at the very top of the manifest-file? Hint: You definitly must not call startService() on your own, the error must be somewhere else

Comment: Yes I have both an InstanceIDListenerService and an IntentService. I did not include them because I believe they are functioning correctly. If I understand correctly, if the response from the HTTP POST to /gcm/send includes success:1, then the token has been updated correctly and that is not the issue, which appears to be the case. And yes, the category package name is identical to the one at the top of the manifest.

Comment: Have you added the token into "registration_ids" in sent message from server-side app

Comment: Yes the token is up to date, otherwise GCM  at least would return a Canonical-ID or fail. I just wanted to ask because maybe the GcmReceiver needs both to function correctly and no the InstanceIDListenerService not necessarily works because getting a Instance-Token does not require this service. When triggering you could try to set the priority of the GCM-notification to "high". The only difference from the client-code you posted compared to mine (which is working) is that I did not set the send-permission in the GcmReceiver

Comment: @s.schmid, you were actually correct in your initial comment; there was an error in the package name for my GCM receiver. Everything's working correctly now. Thank you!